# cython vs python numpy for (simply) adding array

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Sorry if similar questions are already answered. Here is a simplifying example of my question:
the test function calls test_helper which only does some operations with the `numpy` input.

I hope to rewrite test_helper with cython to get speed gain; the restriction is a test and test_helper needs to be separate functions (no inline func) (they are in separate files in real code). But, it's ok to change the inputs to test_helper.

### pure python

```py
# np_test_py.py

import numpy as np
def test_helper(a,b,c):
    d = a + b - c
    return d

def test(a, b, c):
    for i in range(150000):
        test_helper(a, b, c)
```

### best cython so far

```py
# np_test.pyx

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef test_helper(np.float64_t[::1] a, np.float64_t[::1] b, np.float64_t[::1] c):
    cdef:
        int k
        np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] d = np.zeros(2000, dtype=np.float64)
        np.float64_t[::1] d_view = d

    for k in xrange(2000):
        d_view[k] = <np.float64_t>(a[k] + b[k] - c[k])
    return d


def test(a, b, c):
    for i in range(150000):
        test_helper(a, b, c)
```

### profiling (for your reference)

```py
# profiling.py

import pstats, cProfile

import numpy as np
import np_test
import np_test_py

a = np.ones(2000)
b = np.ones(2000)
c = np.ones(2000) * 2

cProfile.runctx("np_test.test(a,b,c)", globals(), locals(), "Profile.prof")
# cProfile.runctx("np_test_py.test(a,b,c)", globals(), locals(), "Profile.prof")

s = pstats.Stats("Profile.prof")
s.strip_dirs().sort_stats("time").print_stats()
```

### setup.py (for your reference)

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("np_test.pyx"),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

### python profiling output (0.32s)

```py
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)                                               
150000    0.297    0.000    0.297    0.000 np_test_py.py:6(test_helper)                                                      
1    0.023    0.023    0.320    0.320 np_test_py.py:10(test)                                                            
1    0.000    0.000    0.320    0.320 {built-in method builtins.exec}                                                   
1    0.000    0.000    0.320    0.320 <string>:1(<module>)                                                              
1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

### cython profiling output (0.666s)

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)                                                        
1    0.666    0.666    0.666    0.666 {np_test.test}                                                                    
1    0.000    0.000    0.666    0.666 {built-in method builtins.exec}                                                   
1    0.000    0.000    0.666    0.666 <string>:1(<module>)                                                              
1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Cython version is actually half the speed of the python version. I thought the reverse should be achievable though (given https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html).

Thanks!

Comment: In you `cython` code you are creating an explicit array of `0`, i.e each elemt gets initialized. I would be quite suprised if the `numpy` addition code would bother initializing the result array. Try using `np.empty` instead

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of the cast `<np.float64_t>` - either it's complete unnecessary (because the result is already that datatype) or it's there to hide an error (in which case you should fix the error!)

Comment: Also - profiling can significantly change the timings you measure: it's useful for getting an idea of where time is spent in a complex program, but for comparing the speed of two simple functions something like `timeit` is much better.

Comment: Have you tried profiling/timing with larger vectors? On my laptop, if the vectors are of size 2000, as in your example, I also see a slower speed in Cython. However, when I increase the size to 20000 or 20000, Cython implementation beats the numpy implementation.

Comment: @FlyingTeller using ```np.empty``` is indeed faster a little 0.666s -> 0.582s

Comment: @DavidW somehow <np.float64_t> casting is a tiny bit faster and agree with you on the timing tool

Comment: @ArdaAytekin yes with 20k instead of 2k, the cython starts to be better than python. The real code problem has vector size of 500 though.
i roughly know this might be due to overhead, but not sure if the threshold for overhead to matter (numpy > cython) is really this low.

Comment: What if instead of creating multiple arrays of 500 floats, your cython function were to take in 2d arrays of shape (500, n)? That way the cost of allocation would only be performed a single time, and the loop over multiple sum arrays would move from python to cython.

Comment: @shucqgz these academic examples do not always give the desired behavior in my opinion. the take-home message for using Cython should be that Cythonizing iterations gives better results over Python iterations. That said, comparing the improvements w.r.t `numpy`, which has optimized matrix algebra routines implemented in FORTRAN, is a bit wrong. Of course, you are using Level-1 operations, which should not differ that much, but in the end you do not know whether vectorizing or any other optimizations are used in `numpy`. Not to mention the calling overhead...

Comment: It looks like the function call overhead leads to bad timings. With larger arrays eg. 20000 cython should be at least as fast or faster (platform/compiler dependent).

Comment: got it. Thanks everyone for your comments.